# Magento- How to customize the shopping cart

Tags: magento

I'm having troubles with displaying product information in shopping cart page.

- please point out the template where i can display this information
- please point out me the way how to find templates that are displayed

Comment: Do you mean you what to add short description in view cart page

Comment: @HariRam: what part of your code is causing you trouble?

Comment: @gowri, i want to display the product details from my database into shopping cart. Not only a short description, all information which includes product name itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show the data in cart line renderer template:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/render/simple.phtml`

and ask the data from `$_item` object in foreach loop and modify the html to your choosing

You can find what templates are used in any magento page by turning on template hints from `system > configuration > developer` section.

Note that if you change a template you should copy the template to your own theme folder first.

Comment: Thank you Anton, this is more informative for fresh developers. Can you explain me more, i have my own database with some product information, is it possible to show the data in this cart. and moreover i am using different templat.

Comment: yes it is possible and don't ask us how as it is your database and your template and we don't know anything about it but we sure do know and can look for samples from magento default code and templates